# How to handle signout when the browser in close in flex 3?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, flex3

My project had audit module, which includes each and every action of the user to be recorded.

When the user closes the browser the audit regarding the logout has to be stored in the database.

I found one solution on the net, but it is working in my machine's IE but failed to work in the friends machine's IE why?
The code is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = clean_up; 
   function clean_up() 
   { 
    var flex = document.${application} || window.${application}; 
    flex.myFlexFunction(); 
   }
```

I placed this code in the index.template.html file in the html-template folder under flex src.

I also placed the below code in my main application.mxml file:

```
      ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",btnLogout);
```

and I defined the logout function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the deal. CAN NOT BE DONE RELIABLY. If this is for audit... you are out of luck and deliver a half baked approach to start with.

Why?

Go to your task manager, kill the IIS process - nothing logs out. No audit. Ergo - the solution does most likely not fulfill the legal audit requirements ;)

Another approach:

- Call a service exvery X seconds from the running page. Like every 5 seconds.
- Assume client dies when you dont receive call for 2 * X seconds (like after 10 seconds).

This way you realize when the client does not connect anymore. Does not stop the user from pulling the network cable and conrinuing viewing, so a failure of the audit method call should wipe the HTML content ;)

But at least you handle browser crashes / terminations, too.